# How to find unique rows by duplicate key

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find rows unique by Car and Color for a specific Model, which have more than 1 color.

```
Car Model   Color
---------------------
Skoda   Fabia   Red
Skoda   Fabia   Blue
Skoda   Fabia   Red
Skoda   Octavia Red
```

I need to show results like this:

```
Skoda Fabia Red
Skoda Fabia Blue
```

And I don't want to see this:

```
Skoda Octavia Red
```

I tried this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE Model = 'Fabia' 
GROUP BY (Car, Color) 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: `SELECT Car, Model, Color FROM data WHERE Model = 'Fabia' GROUP BY Car, Model, Color HAVING COUNT(*)>1`

Comment: Define does not work?  i assuming you don't get the correct results or you get a only_full_group_by error?

Comment: I can have good results but they showing also rows with less than two unique records.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select distinct c.*
from cars c
where model = 'Fabia' and
      exists (select 1
              from cars c2
              where c2.model = c.model and
                    c2.car = c.car and
                    c2.color <> c.color
             );
```

Or, if you are content with the colors in one column:

```
select car, model, group_concat(distinct color)
from cars c2
where model = 'Fabia'
group by car, model
having count(distinct color) > 1;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `group_concat(...)` might require `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = <larger_number>;` for the larger groups as it silently truncates (without a error) after 1024 chars..

Comment: Still HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT color) does not work (0 results).

Comment: @ŁukaszTrześniewski i very much doubt that.. Should work fine on your example data in this question..

Comment: I think so, but my table is more complicated than this from example :/

Comment: *"I think so, but my table is more complicated than this from example "* These queries are not flawed @ŁukaszTrześniewski your example is flawed consider providing a beter one see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for help...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT distinct a.* FROM data as a 
JOIN 
(SELECT Car, Model,count(1)
 FROM data 
 GROUP BY Car, Model 
 HAVING count(1) > 1) as b
ON a.Model=b.Model AND a.Car=b.Car;
```

Comment: Did you tested this? As on first seight this would select `Skoda Octavia Red` (which the topicstarter did want to have) as in the inner select will look for duplicated colors within model..

Comment: Yeah I did. The inner select will return Skoda Fabia, since it has more than 1 count.

Comment: *"The inner select will return Skoda Fabia, since it has more than 1 count"* No the inner SQL will return `Red  Fabia` as the inner SQL will look for duplicated colors within model   -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mhKCFB2UKmqpSkaMYv1dYE/2

Comment: Oh I got it i actually interchanged the field names, let me correct it. @RaymondNijland edited it

Answer (score 0):

I have solution:

```
SELECT *,group_concat(DISTINCT Color) FROM data WHERE model='Fabia' GROUP BY Car HAVING count(DISTINCT Color)>1
```